# Maximum Notation of Multivariable Function

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus

I have a multivariable function that is composed of six variables; four of these are constants $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4$ and the other two variables are $x$ and $y$. The function is defined as follows $$\Xi(x,y,C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4)$$. I would like to find the maximum value of $\Xi$ over $x \in \{-\infty,\infty\}$ and $y \in \{-\infty,\infty\}$. What is the rigorous mathematical notation I should use to describe this. Is this fine: $$\mathrm{max}\{\Xi(x,y,C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4)\}$$?

Comment: If it uses four constants, isn't it just a function of $2$ variables?

Comment: @m1cky22 Correct, but what is the notation?

Comment: First, don't include the constants in your function. You can just say $\Xi(x,y)$. I think it's pretty clear what you're saying if you say max, and include the intervals of $x$ and $y$